# How to target specific children of .not($(this)) on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, repeater

I'm working with a list of repeated figures with images inside of them and am applying hover effects. Of these figures, every one except the one being hovered over should change on mouseover. Since there's a figcaption within each figure, the initial hover should target the entire figure, not just the image within it (because I'd like to change the styling of the text on hover as well).

For example, when I hover over a figure, it should stay full color while the other's text and imgs go down in opacity and/or change to greyscale.

I've been successful adding a class to the figure itself, but not the elements within it. Here's the code I've been using:

```
<figure class="thumb">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
  <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="thumb">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
  <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="thumb">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
  <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
</figure>

var $thisthis = '.thumb p';

$('.thumb').on('mouseover', function(event) {
  $('.thumb').not($(this)).addClass('hover');
});

$('.thumb').on('mouseout', function() {
  $('.thumb').not($(this)).removeClass('hover');
});
```

When I change the JQuery to this in order to target specific elements that are not in $(this), it breaks.

```
$('.thumb').on('mouseover', function(event) {
  $('.thumb figcaption').not($(this)).addClass('hover');
});

$('.thumb').on('mouseout', function() {
  $('.thumb figcaption').not($(this)).removeClass('hover');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samseurynck/ka2Xs/57/

I'm sure it's something wrong with how I'm targeting the elements, but I can't seem to figure out the right way to approach it.

Thanks all!

Comment: See if `$('.thumb').not($(this)).find('figcaption')` (before the add and remove class commands) works for you.

Comment: Seems like it isn't working! Just tested it today.